# 12.04 or 14.04 for an old computer?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

I searched on web about this question and mostly, I found that 14.04 is a way better than 12.04. 
but only one answer I found, that say "I am using an old computer and weirdly, I found that 12.04 works better than 14.04"

so I got a doubt, and I want to ask here,
this laptop have:

2 GB memory (DDR2)
Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T5450 @ 1.66GHz × 2 Processor
Intel® 965GM x86/MMX/SSE2 Graphics
32-bit OS type

which version of Ubuntu, you prefer?

Comment: Try Xubuntu 14.04 or Lubuntu 14.04 for lightweight UIs.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed 14.04 on a Dell Dimension 3100 (specs: http://www.engadget.com/products/dell/dimension/3100/specs/ ) and it's working, albeit a bit sluggishly with no lowering of eye candy.  Aside from some kind of particular incompatibility, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to run 14.x just fine with the specifications you posted.

Comment: :/ you re right I think. I wonder about that because just I was using 14.04 and there was a no  problem about playing counter strike 1.6 on wine. than, I updated it to 14.04.1 and now when I click cs to run it from wine, wine says that "it is corrupted, please obtain a new copy" :(
EDIT: well, it was also playing on lubuntu very well, but I found lubuntu so... you know, worse than ubuntu so I got back to ubuntu 14.04.1 and now wine sucks on everything .

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 on an old HP Compaq 6715b with 1.5GB RAM and a 2.2GHz single core CPU, it's working fine, although I'm considering moving to Lubuntu to further improve performance.

14.04 does not perform considerably worse than 12.04 (*in my opinion*), but the desktop environment does matter.

So I'd recommend going for 14.04, Xubuntu if you're more after features and Lubuntu if you want better performance.